# What causes Lucene.Net to be unable to find one of its files?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

We're getting random, sporadic issues on our Lucene.Net-based application.  They look like this:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'G:\Site\App_Data\Model Index\index\_2y0.fnm'.
```

Is this symptomatic of something we're doing wrong?  We close all readers and all searchers.  I optimize regularly.  What would cause something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are doing something wrong. If you are using a very old version of Lucene.Net like 2.0.0.4, upgrade to 2.9.2 or newer

Comment: Once I upgraded, it got a lot better.  I still had concurrency issues occasionally, but they went way down.